# Connection to Amazon RDS MySQL instance fails with `init_connect command failed`

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm attempting to open a connection from my Amazon RDS instance to my local dev machine. I added my IP to the security policy in Amazon's panel (read: whitelisted myself in the firewall) and added my user in MySQL:

```
grant usage on bar.* to foo@0.0.0.0 identified by "foobar";
grant all privileges on bar.* to foo@0.0.0.0;
```

Assume that `0.0.0.0` is actually my IP.

I then attempt to connect via the command-line MySQL client:

[wk@batman ~]$ mysql  --host=1.1.1.1 --user=foo -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 66287753
Server version: 5.6.17-log

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, SkySQL Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

```
MySQL [(none)]> show databases;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    66287829
Current database: *** NONE ***

ERROR 1184 (08S01): Aborted connection 66287829 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'foo' host: 0.0.0.0 (init_connect command failed)
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this error - the results I could find on Google pertained to database replication. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the user does not have execute grant global, to fix it

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON *.* TO user_name;
```

Comment: I was going nuts over this issue. I have to read about execute now. Thanks